# Convergent stochastic process can't be iid?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If we have a stochastic process $\{X_n , n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ for which we have $X_n \rightarrow{X}$ in probability does that imply that $X_n$ can't be iid unless the $X_n=C\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Not by definition, a stochastic process is just a collection of random variables defined on a common probability space.

Comment: How about $X_{n}$ being iid copies of $X$?

Comment: @Tobsn You mean $X_1=X_2=...=X$? But that can never be independent right (unless again $X$ is indeed a constant)?

Comment: they are equal only in distribution

Comment: @Tobsn Yes that would converge trivially in distribution to $X$ but not in probability. (Unless $X_n$ is a constant).

Comment: Yep, I am convinced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X_n$ are independent random variables with $X_n \to X$ in probability. Then $X$ is measurable with respect to the tail sigma algebra $\mathcal{T}$ of the sequence $(X_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$. By [Kolmogorov's 0-1 law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law), this sigma algebra is trivial, i.e., for any $A \in \mathcal{T}$, $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0,1\}$. This implies, for example, that if $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X \leq b) >0$, then $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X \leq b) = 1$. The natural argument with [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) then shows that there exists a number $C$ with $\mathbb{P}(X=C) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality you can assume that $X_n\to X$ a.s. (pass to a subsequence if necessary), and (ii) $|X_n(\omega)|\le C$ for some constant $C$, and likewise for $X$ (replace $X_n$ by $\arctan X_n$ to make this happen, etc.). Key observation:  under the above conditions, if the $X_n$ are iid, then each $X_n$ is independent of $X$. Now compute $E[(X_n-X)^2]$ and then let $n\to\infty$.